# Difference between the verbs 'jolt and jerk' in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Leaving aside all the meanings the words *jolt* and *jerk* have, I'd like to concentrate on their use when intransitive and performed by a person who is caught by surprise or horror as in the sentence:

> She **jerked/jolted** in horror.

Do these words imply a single jump from the shock or a more continuous motion in a certain a direction? Is there a difference, in this context, between the two?

Comment: As James says, it's a single sudden motion here, but in another context it could be multiple spasms. *She began to jerk as the potion took effect.*

Comment: Jerk is what something at the end of a rope does when the rope is pulled suddenly. Jolt is what a wheeled vehicle does as it travels down a bumpy road. To say that she jerked suggests that her body moved some part of it itself in a manner suggesting a whip. If she jolted then she moved as knocked off balance by an outside force. In either case her reaction was unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jolt is usually used transitively. Its intransitive use is rather less common, perhaps limited to describing the shaking of a vehicle:

> The car started to jolt as it went off-road.

There is also the possibility of the transitive use, with the object being omitted by ellipsis.

In your example, "She jerked in horror" is better than "jolted" as it means a single sudden motion.